# Similar Package like Enchant in R

Tags: r, spell-checking, hunspell, enchant

I have a query.
There is a package in python called "Enchant"
Enchant is a module in python which is used to check the spelling of a word, gives suggestions to correct words. Also, gives antonym and synonym of words. It checks whether a word exists in dictionary or not. 
In this module, we can define our own dictionary.

Can you tell me if there is a similar package available in R.
I checked hunspell but I am not able to define my own dictionary.

Can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

R has a `spelling` package. See https://cran.r-project.org/package=spelling. It doesn't provide synonyms and antonyms.